# JS function which executes on page load not being tracked by Jasmine spy

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This is my `test_sp.js`:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function() {
    var ctrl, mockBaseService;

    beforeEach(function() {

        mockBaseService = {
            sps: 'x',
            cerrorMessages: 'y',
            add: { sp: function(something, cb) { cb() } },
            fetch: { selfsps: function(cb) { cb() } },
            logout: function() {},
        };


        module('BaseApp', function($provide) {
            $provide.value('BaseService', mockBaseService);
        });

        module('SpPageApp');


        inject(function($controller) {
            ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
            });
        });

        spyOn(mockBaseService.fetch, 'selfsps');

    });

     it('should fetch sps from BaseService.fetch.selfsps right away.', function() {
         expect(mockBaseService.fetch.selfsps).toHaveBeenCalled();
     });

});
```

This is my `sp.js`:

```
angular.module("SpPageApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {

        var self = this;

        // Call BaseService.fetch.selfsps at the beginning of the file.
        BaseService.fetch.selfsps(function() {
            self.sps = BaseService.sps;
            self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
        });

        self.add = function() {
            BaseService.add.sp(self.sp, function() {
                self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
            });
        };    
    }]);
```

`BaseService` is in the `BaseApp` module in `base.js`.

With that said, when I test the code by doing `karma start`, I get this error:

```
    Expected spy selfsps to have been called.
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/a/Documents/CMS/CMSApp/static/js/karma/tests/test_sp.js:59:56)
Chromium 47.0.2526 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 5 of 5 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.105 secChromium 47.0.2526 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 5 of 5 (1 FAILED) (0.15 secs / 0.105 secs)
```

and points to this line:

```
expect(mockBaseService.fetch.selfsps).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

How come `mockBaseService.fetch.selfsps` is not called, even though in my `sp.js`, I am calling it at the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by instantiating the controller. That calls the `BaseService.fetch.selfsps()`function. And then only, you start spying on that function. It's too late.

You need to spy before instantiating the controller. Just like, if you want to spy on a phone conversation, you need to start listening before the conversation starts. If you start listening after the conversation has ended, you won't hear anything.